# ScheduledExecutorService not executing task with an initialDelay 0

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

`ScheduledExecutorService` not executing a submitted task with an `initialDelay` of `0` time units when using `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate`. But it is executing the task when i call [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) on it

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("I am a runnable");
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(runnable, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Output

```
I am a runnable
```

But when I use `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` instead of `schedule` the task is not getting executed.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("I am a runnable");
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// or  scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Why is the task not getting executed in this scenario? I expected this task to be executed as the `initialDelay` is set to `0`

Comment: Still, what's strange is that I couldn't find any async call inside `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which might causing this to happen. If this is not the case then there must be some overhead in executing the task before returning the API call.

Comment: I think the answer by [zysaaa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70471134/9276996) resembles closer to this scenario

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your call to [`ExecutorService#shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) stops any further scheduling of tasks. Apparently your call happens so quickly that the scheduler never got to execute the first run of the scheduled task. This makes sense.

What does not quite make sense is why a call to `schedule` happens to get scheduled fast enough to get its task executed in time before the shutdown, but calls to `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` with a delay of zero do not get scheduled as quickly. Apparently there is some overhead in the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` and `scheduleAtFixedRate` calls, enough overhead that the program exits before they get a chance to make their first executions.

Anyways, you can see the behavior in my version of your code [running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CCz1iH). Adding this line:

```
Thread.sleep( 1_000 * 5 ) ;
```

… before your shutdown gives enough time for some of the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` and `scheduleAtFixedRate` tasks to execute.

Or see the same effect by adding a call to `awaitTermination` as shown in [correct Answer by Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70470616/642706).

Comment: @matt For *repeating scheduled* tasks, that means a task’s execution that is currently underway gets to finish, but no more repetitions of that task after will be scheduled. Otherwise, we would have no way to halt repeating tasks.

Comment: @matt In theory I would think a repeating task with *a delay of zero* would execute as quickly as a `schedule` call. But apparently not. Apparently there is indeed some overhead in the scheduleWithFixedDelay and scheduleAtFixedRate calls, enough overhead that the program exits before they get a chance to make their first executions.

Comment: I think @matt is also right, in layman terms `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` with an initial delay of 0 should be executed to maintain the semantics

Comment: ```Apparently there is some overhead in the scheduleWithFixedDelay and scheduleAtFixedRate calls, enough overhead that the program exits before they get a chance to make their first executions.```   Hi, Basil, I have some disagreement with this passage, I wrote an answer, can you take a look

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind can be found in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, which is the implementation class of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`

### 1. Task is executed when calling `schedule`,

it is due to [executeExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdown is true by default](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+29/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java#L172)

```java
    /**
     * False if should cancel non-periodic not-yet-expired tasks on shutdown.
     */
    private volatile boolean executeExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdown = true;
```

### 2. Task is not executed for `scheduleWithFixedDelay` or `scheduleAtFixedRate`

it is due to [continueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdown is false by default](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+29/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java#L167)

```java
    /**
     * False if should cancel/suppress periodic tasks on shutdown.
     */
    private volatile boolean continueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdown;
```

We can override these parameters by [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(boolean)) and [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(boolean)) before scheduling the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Why `shutdown` is called immediately, `schedule` can perform this task, but `scheduleAtFixedRate` does not perform this task?

If `scheduleAtFixedRate` is used, then this task is `Periodic`, and default `keepPeriodic` policy is `false`, so this task will be removed from work queue when `shutdown` is called.

But using `schedule` does not perform the logic of removing task.(`isPeriodic` is false.)

See `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#onShutdown`:

```
        @Override void onShutdown() {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = super.getQueue();
        boolean keepDelayed =
            getExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy();
        boolean keepPeriodic =
            getContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy();
        // Traverse snapshot to avoid iterator exceptions
        // TODO: implement and use efficient removeIf
        // super.getQueue().removeIf(...);
        for (Object e : q.toArray()) {
            if (e instanceof RunnableScheduledFuture) {
                RunnableScheduledFuture<?> t = (RunnableScheduledFuture<?>)e;
                if ((t.isPeriodic()
                     ? !keepPeriodic
                     : (!keepDelayed && t.getDelay(NANOSECONDS) > 0))
                    || t.isCancelled()) { // also remove if already cancelled
                    if (q.remove(t))
                        t.cancel(false);
                }
            }
        }
        tryTerminate();
    }
```

So I think the explanation from Basil Bourque's answer is inaccurate:

> Apparently there is some overhead in the scheduleWithFixedDelay and scheduleAtFixedRate calls, enough overhead that the program exits before they get a chance to make their first executions.

It's not because program exits before they get a chance to make their first executions, but because the worker threads in the thread pool did not get the task(It was removed,), and then the thread pool stop. At this time, the program exits. If the task is not removed, the program will not exit immediately.  Only when the worker thread in the thread pool have completed the tasks in the work queue, the program will exit. (Because the worker thread in the thread pool are not daemon threads).

Comment: Yes, I agree, this might be the issue, the task which has to be executed has been removed before the worker got a chance to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You shutdown the executor too early. That's why other thread is not started yet. There is no guarantee that thread will start first then shutdown method.

If you use awaitTermination you will see the output.

```
scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

//Output: I am a runnable